# Mac Terminal 'cd' to a folder alias

Tags: macos, terminal

I have created an alias of a folder called 'htdocs alias' and when i type in terminal cd 'htdocs alias' or cd htdocs\ alias it doesnt work?

any reasons why this is happening? or any suggestions to help this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mac OS aliases are more similar to Windows shortcuts than to Unix symlinks; you can double-click them but you cannot `cd` into them.

[This article](http://web.archive.org/web/20100615001122/http://www.warrenmoore.net/blog/2010/01/09/make-terminal-follow-aliases-like-symlinks/) explains how to make `cd` follow OS X aliases:

> This is a two-part process requiring a little familiarity with gcc and bash, but I’ll try to make it as simple as possible. Firstly, you need this file: [getTrueName.c](http://web.archive.org/web/20100110234300/http://www.macosxhints.com/dlfiles/getTrueName.txt). This file was created by Thos Davis and is licensed under the GPLv2. Save it anywhere, then compile it with the following command:
>
> ```
> gcc -o getTrueName -framework Carbon getTrueName.c
> ```
>
> This will create the ‘getTrueName’ executable in the same directory as the source. You can add it to your PATH, or just copy it directly to /usr/bin so it’s easy to access.
>
> Interestingly, when Terminal opens a new shell, .bashrc is not executed as you might expect. Instead, under the login shell, .bash_profile is executed. So, add the following to .bash_profile in your Home directory. You might need to create it first; it isn’t there by default.
>
> ```
> cd() {
>   if [[ -f "$1" || -L "$1" ]]; then
>     path=$(getTrueName "$1")
>     builtin cd "$path"
>   else
>     builtin cd "$@"
>   fi
> }
> ```
>
> *[edited the function a bit –grawity]*

Comment: Alternatively, it's quite easy to create an OS X Service that creates symlinks and can be assigned the keyboard shortcut `Cmd-L` instead.

Comment: The linked article no longer exists.

Comment: Fixed, @ChrisPage.

Comment: Are you sure `==` works? Shouldn't it be `-eq`? `${#1}` also doesn't look right, `$#` should suffice...

Comment: @DanielBeck: I just quoted the entire article, hadn't really looked into the wrapper function.

Comment: Here is another version of the article: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050828054129701

Comment: Also, here is a duplicate question on stackoverflow with other answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781500/how-can-i-cd-to-an-alias-directory-in-the-mac-osx-terminal